# First isomorphism theorem of sheaves -- do you need to sheafify if the map is surjective on basis sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Say I have two sheaves $\mathscr F, \mathscr G$ of rings over a topological space $X$, and basis set $\mathscr B \subset \mathscr P(X)$. Say I've specified a morphism $\mathscr F \rightarrow \mathscr G$ over elements of $\mathscr B$, such that each $\mathscr F(U) \rightarrow \mathscr G(U)$ is surjective ($U \in \mathscr B$).  I think this is enough to specify a surjective morphism $\phi: \mathscr F \rightarrow \mathscr G$, right?  Then I can take the quotient presheaf $\mathscr F / ker(\phi)$.  But this presheaf is now isomorphic to $\mathscr G$, and is therefore a sheaf.  Is that correct?

Comment: No it is not correct : a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ might induces surjective maps $\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}(U)$ for each $U$ in a basis but not for other $U$, so the quothent presheaf $\mathcal{F}/\ker\phi$ will not be a sheaf. For example, take $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ the map $\mathcal{C}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^\times_X$ be the exponential of continuous functions. Then this map is surjective on sections for every simply connected open subset which certainly forms a basis of the topology.

Comment: @Roland ah, ok. thank you